# How Often Is "Contributors" Section Updated on Bitcoin.Org

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin.org

Believe I have a screenshot of contributors organized by number of commits that can be found [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/development#dev-communities). Does anyone know how often this list is updated? Currently I count 361 contributors on that list bit the github repo [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) list 786 contributors, leading me to believe it has been a while.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the list of contributors is automatically generated by this script:
https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/Bitcoin.org/blob/master/_plugins/contributors.rb

and is refreshed every 24h (as stated in a comment in the script itself).

I suppose that the difference in the counts depends on the fact that anonymous contributions are excluded in the github API request (you should add `anon=1` to have all contributors).